# Which template Symfony is using when we do not specify a template's name explicitly in @Template annotations?

Tags: symfony, templates

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="root")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="id")
     * @Template("SensioBlogBundle:Post:show.html.twig")
     */
    public function themeAction($id)
    {
    }

}
```

I can understand this case:

```
@Template("SensioBlogBundle:Post:show.html.twig")
```

but what is happening when @Template is empty?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html

Here i didn't find the answer to the question.

Comment: Read The doc (RTFM) http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html If the template is named after the controller and action names, which is the case for the above example, you can even omit the annotation value

Answer (score 0):

When you don't specify a template Symfony takes automatically the Template

```
BundleName/Resources/views/Some/index.html.twig
```

So in Your case create a folder `Some` for your controller and a file `indexActionName.html.twig` in your example its the index action that is why its ìndex.html.twig` in your case.

Comment: thanks for your reply. That if i don't want to create BundleName/Resources/views/Some/index.html.twig. Will this mean that twig files (for instance "base.html.twig" or another) in this path "app\Resources\views\" will be using?

Comment: NO! "app" is not in your Bundle ;) you should really read the documentation.